# Django + IIS windows server 2008

Tags: django, iis

Hi I am trying to install django on IIS by following this guide http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXbfHtAvubc#t=194 but at the end I always get this error

Python 3.4 
Django 1.7.1
Windows Server 2008R2 IIS 7.5

---

file Wsgi.py

```
   import os
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Plastimi.settings")
```

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

---

---

Environment Variables

NAME : WSGI_HANDLER

VALUE: django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()

---

> Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\Plastimi\wfastcgi.py", line
>   711, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
>   File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\Plastimi\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in
>   read_wsgi_handler return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name) File
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Django\Plastimi\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in
>   get_wsgi_handler handler = handler() File
>   "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 14, in
>   get_wsgi_application django.setup() File
>   "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 20, in setup
>   configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING) File
>   "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 46, in
>   **getattr** self._setup(name) File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 40, in
>   _setup % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either
>   define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings. StdOut: StdErr:

Comment: One will not watch the video, tell exactly what you were trying that you faced the problem.

Answer (score 1):

WSGI_HANDLER: replace *django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()* with *django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()*

django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler() is deprecated from 1.4

a good video tutorial with text explanation you can find on http://chrisberragan.com/posts/2014/03/19/installing-django-on-iis-7-5/